# How to avoid text wrapping in multiline TextView between two words?

Tags: android, html, textview

I would like to display some text in a TextView, but I would like to avoid text wrapping in a specific position of the text, to avoid the text to display like this:

```
This is my very long text
:
```

Instead, I want my text to display as following:

```
This is my very long
text :
```

You may ask: why is there a space before `:`?

Simply because it's in French, and, unlike English, you're supposed to add an extra space before this character (also available with `?` and `!`).

I tried this:

```
    TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.my_text);
    myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("This is my very long <span style=\"white-space: nowrap;\">text :</span>"));
```

But of course, it doesn't work.

I was also thinking of a specific character that behaves like a space but without wrapping. I don't know if it exists, and if it's a good practice.

Answer (score 2):

I finally found out a solution for the specific white space wrapping problem: just add `\u202F` instead of your white space in your string, like for example:

```
<string name="my_string">This is my very long text\u202F:</string>
```